# How are assets/public directories accessed in web servers?

Tags: http, web, browser

Whenever you reference something in your `public` or `assets` directory via `link/script` tags, are you only downloading what you reference?

For example, say I have an enormous amount of images in my `public` directory. Only images that are referenced on that particular page are downloaded, right?

Taking this further, say your stylesheet references a lot of images, and it serves every single page on the your website. So are all of those images downloaded?

You see, I'm probably lacking some fundamental background on this as I'm pretty new to web dev, and I don't have much experience with nginx/apache or the like. Please explain!

Comment: Browsers will download only what they told and need to download. In case of CSS only images from matched rules would be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the browser has no idea, what files are located on the server. It only knows those paths that are referenced in HTML (via `<link/>`, `<script/>`, `<img/>`, `<a/>`, etc.).

You can also have a look at the so called *access log* of your web server or (better) your browser's developer tools ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en)) to investigate what happens under the hood.